# Python [Errno 13] - Exception handling when saving a file that is opened by user

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, xlsxwriter, errno

I'm using Pandas and Xlsxwriter to analyze some data, and then periodically create a Excel simple report for another users. The report should always get overwritten by the last one I export. Also, once I export it, it gets automatically opened to review it quickly.

The only issue I have is that I get an [Errno 13] if someone has left that file opened (or even if I'm using it, which I must admit happens).

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '2320PLFY2018.xlsx'
```

So i just wanted to add some Error handling to that IOError at the end of the XLSXWRITER part, to let me know about it, and give me a chance to close the file. Started with a simple attempt just to give me an error message. Tried several times but cant make it work. This is one attempt:

```
try:
    writer.save()
    os.startfile(company_code_choice + 'PLFY2018.xlsx')
except IOError as e:
    print(e.errno)
```

Also tried without specifying the Error type:

```
while True:
    try:
        writer.save()
        os.startfile(company_code_choice + 'PLFY2018.xlsx')
        break
    except:
        print "Close the file!"
```

I'm new to creating code so I apologize if this is an obvious question... 
I've been googling for this all morning and read several other questions but couldn't make it work on my code. Thanks in advance-

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? A detailed description of what you expect to happen in the case where the file is already opened is really needed here. Also don't use bare except blocks as they will create a whole host of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just want the program not to crash, and let me know someone has it opened. If it is me, I could close it and continue... The error I get is IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '2320PLFY2018.xlsx', which makes sense since it cannot overwrite the file...

Comment: If you simply need to quickly hack together an answer to this you could always just add retry condition in the exception handler that will give you the chance to close the file.

Comment: The thing is, those two didnt even wroked for me, they didnt printed those statements, I got the same error as before adding the error handling code. Is there anything wrong with that code? In the first attempt, shouldnt I get a printed statement instead of the classic "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '2320PLFY2018.xlsx'" ?

Comment: @shuttle87 doesnt the second attempt work as a retry condition? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NovinShahroudi
 IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '2320PLFY2018.xlsx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing that I can think of that may cause this error is that one of the functions that you call inside your `try` statement is handling the exception inside itself so that your exception handling becomes ineffective.

To make sure:

1. Try to throw an exception manually from your `try` block so that you make sure the exception handling works in general.
2. If the aforementioned assumption is true you can figure out which function is handling the exception inside itself by manually raising an exception once before and once after the call.

To demonstrate what I mean:

```
while True:
    sleep(1)
    try:
        raise Exception("my exception")
        writer.save()
        os.startfile(company_code_choice + 'PLFY2018.xlsx')
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Close the file: ", e)
```

You should definitely capture your raised exception otherwise, something is wrong with your code. Try to simply or check what prevents the excepted behavior if happened. If you could capture your raised exception then the next time:

```
while True:
    sleep(1)
    try:
        writer.save()
        raise Exception("my exception")
        os.startfile(company_code_choice + 'PLFY2018.xlsx')
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Close the file: ", e)
```

So that you either capture your raised exception which means `writer.save()` does not handle the exception inside itself or you get the same error which means `writer.save()` handles the exception. By continuing this procedure all over the `try` block of your code you must be able to figure out which function is making trouble.

That's the best thing I can think of now. I hope it helps. But if I'm right then you could only figure out the source of the error but I don't know how you can achieve the behavior you would like. So maybe you can find a clue on the documentation.

Comment: Using your method, found out that ´writer.save´ was handling the exception. Thanks! Will try to find an alternative checking for the open file before that line....